# In Android how do I resolve conflicting Android Theme Errors involving Chips and Material Themes?

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I have been reading Android developer documentation and SO questions for hours trying to figure out how to use Chips and Materials themes, together. The stack trace is seemingly contradictory in what it wants, and I cannot figure out what is happening.

Here is the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="275dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteY="60dp"
        android:elevation="7dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/card_header"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_header"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">                

                <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:id="@+id/genre_chips"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The gradle file:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

The styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cotoure_font</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The chip style xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Finally, here is where I'm attempting to create the Chips dynamically:

```
for (genre in genres) {
                val chip =
                        LayoutInflater
                        .from(context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_chip_category, null, false) as Chip
                chip.text = genre
                holder.chips.addView(chip)
            }
```

What I don't understand is I can create Chips just fine in the XML files, but when I try to add them dynamically I get this stack trace:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
W/Chip: Chip text must be vertically center and start aligned
E/ThemeUtils: View class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
W/Chip: Chip text must be vertically center and start aligned
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.karbon.foundry.myapplication, PID: 11552
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.karbon.foundry.sdc.adapters.GameListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GameListAdapter.kt:81)
        at com.karbon.foundry.sdc.adapters.GameListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GameListAdapter.kt:27)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable.loadFromAttributes(ChipDrawable.java:338)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(ChipDrawable.java:280)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:201)
        at com.google.android.material.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.java:191)
            ... 63 more
```

The stack trace is complaining about both `View class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).` and `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).` Don't those conflict with each other? I have tried to use `Theme.AppCompat`, but then it complains about needing Material, then I tried using `Theme.MaterialComponents...Bridge` as it is now, doesn't work. Also tried it without `.Bridge`. I need to create the chips dynamically as there are over 50 possibilities and I don't want to add 50 possible chips to the xml files. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: How do you initialize the adapter? Which context are you using?